# JQuery .bind() / .unbind() problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with `.bind()` and `.unbind()` in JQuery, even though my situation is seemingly identical to an example given on the JQuery site. In this case, the bind/unbind is applied to a JQuery tab (one of many). When the tab is clicked, it loads a controller action through ajax.

```
# show.html.erb:
$(document).ready( function(){
    var projectNav = function(){
        $("#tabs-project .loadingDiv").show();
        $.ajax({ url: "<%= url_for(params.except(:action).merge(:action => 'show_project')) %>", dataType: 'script' })
    };
    $("#projectMenuButton").bind('click', projectNav);
});

# show_project.js.erb
$("#tabs-project .loadingDiv").remove();
$("#tabs-project").append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "profiles/project")%>')
$("#projectMenuButton").unbind('click', projectNav);
```

The `.unbind()` part isn't working like that - clicking the menu button again reloads the partial again.

When I change the existing unbind to `$("#projectMenuButton").unbind('click');`, it unbinds everything including the tab's principal function (to switch the view to the right div).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scope problem... `projectNav` is only defined within the scope of the `$(document).ready`, so it is undefined when passed into `unbind`. A solution:

```
# show.html.erb:
var projectNav = function(){
        $("#tabs-project .loadingDiv").show();
        $.ajax({ url: "<%= url_for(params.except(:action).merge(:action => 'show_project')) %>", dataType: 'script' })
};
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#projectMenuButton").bind('click', projectNav);
});

# show_project.js.erb
$("#tabs-project .loadingDiv").remove();
$("#tabs-project").append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "profiles/project")%>')
$("#projectMenuButton").unbind('click', projectNav);
```